# Which airports can I transit through when traveling from PHX(Phoenix) to BOM(Mumbai) with a unstamped H1B visa?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, passport-stamps, h1b-visas

I am a Indian with a valid H1B visa which is not stamped. I would be traveling from PHX to BOM during the summer vacations (may-july 2019). Which are the airports I cannot transit through during my outgoing and incoming journey? The major transit points I am interested in are -

Canada
Dubai
Frankfurt
London
Paris
Hong Kong
Shanghai
Singapore
Munich
Vienna
Abu Dhabi
Doha

Alternatively, I would be thankful if you could guide me to a resource where I can find this information.

Comment: The "stamp" terminology used to refer to getting a US visa in your passport but isn't normally used anymore. If you don't have the visa in your passport, you may have H-1B *status* but it's not accurate to say you have an H-1B *visa*.  Will you get the visa in your passport during the trip?  Do you have any other visas in your passport? (If not, how did you enter the US?)  Please edit your question to specify these.

Comment: @krubo Since my H1B visa was renewed while I was in the US, it would have to be stamped again (which cannot be done in the US)

Comment: krubo explained it correctly; you do not have an H-1B _visa_, you have H-1B _status_. You will not have a _visa_ again until you apply for it at a consulate and have it placed in your passport. Regardless of your itinerary, you need to bring your I-797.

Comment: @Michael Hampton so which airports can I transit through?